# How collections are working?

Tags: magento-1.8, collection

How collections are working in magento? I have a bit idea about it, can anybody explain this in brief?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a pretty broad question.

Basically a collection is from a resource class in an extension that specifies the table to use. This class extends the core resource class which in it's turn extends a Varien Collection class which ends up using Zend to create the actual query that is executed. For each result a Varien Object is returned with the data. But there's a whole lot more to it.

Here are some links that will tell you a lot more about collections.

- [Magento wiki Collections](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento)
- [Magento wiki Using Collections](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento)
- [Varien Data Collections by Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/magento_collections)
- [Excellence blog](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-part12-series-collection-sql-operations)